# yii2 : kartik select2 in popup modal

Tags: yii2, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2, yii2-basic-app, kartik-v

I used to use kartik in many projects and its working fine even in popup modal , but in this way I do not know why

**in controller**

```
 $model = new LogFile();
   $file_position= $_GET['file_position'];

   $canTransferTo = new CourtDepartment();
   $canTransferTo = CourtDepartment::find()
        ->where(['id'=>$file_position])
        ->one();
    $CourtDepartment = CourtDepartment::find()
        ->where('id in ('. $canTransferTo->canTransferTo.')')
        ->all();
```

**in my _form.php**

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'move_to')->widget(\kartik\widgets\Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($CourtDepartment
    , 'id', 'name'),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Choose Court department')],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
 ]); ?>
```

when i click the **button**

```
  <?= Html::button(Yii::t('app', 'Move File'), ['value' => Url::to(['log-file/create','rippId'=>$model->rippId, 'file_position'=>$model->file_position]),'class' => 'btn btn-primary addNew', 'id'=>'addNew']); ?>
```

i get this message in console

> GET http:[My Site Name]?r=log-file%2Fcreate&rippId=1-10-151&file_position=2 500 (Internal Server Error)

but if i open the link in new tab its works fine

Comment: look into the console for the error details against the request , `500` is a server side error

Comment: I know , but when I open the link in new tab not in popup it's works fine .